# Dividing a geo map until getting no results in python

Tags: python

I have access to an API, that gets lat and lng of north-east and south-west of a block on map, and returns **30 top** places in that block, and also **total number** of available items in the block (let's assume that is 1000). To get all 1000 places, I have to make the block smaller (by giving the middle of the block to the API and dividing it to four smaller blocks) and get 30 top places for these new smaller blocks, and I have to continue making the blocks smaller until I get less than 30 results.

I can make tens or hundreds of small blocks and check they're results, but the places are not evenly distributed and this will cause lots of unnecessary requests with empty responses.

How can I write a function to get all 1000 places from this API?

Here is the sample code to get top 30 places from the initial block:

```py
#ne: north-east, sw: south-west
nelat = 35.7921
nelng = 51.6147
swlat = 35.6888
swlng = 51.1973

ne = str(nelat) + "," + str(nelng)
sw = str(swlat) + "," + str(swlng)
url = "https://example.com/places?ne=" + ne + "&sw=" + sw
response = requests.request("GET", url)

total_places = response.json()["total_places"] # 1000
current_top_places = response.json()["top_places"]
### and store current_top_places somewhere (this part is not a problem)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your API return upon one request getting fired?

Comment: @nithin11 as it's in the sample code, it returns "total_places" (number of total places) and "top_places" (an array of 30 top places in the area).

Comment: So your API returns two things?/

Comment: If the API already returns the top_places and the total_places, what is your requirement exactly?

Comment: @nithin11 It returns only 30 results, and I need to change the lat and lng to eventually get all the 1000 places.